# Linear Layouts Overlapping

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

For some reason my LinearLayouts that I am adding to my RelativeLayout that is within a ScrollView are overlapping each other.
I assume there is some way of setting the LinearLayouts so they would position themselves below the LinearLayout above?

```
 exampleLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.examplelayout);


         exampleButton = new TextView[exampleListCount];

         LinearLayout.LayoutParams rowsLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         rowsLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
         rowsLayoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);

         LinearLayout.LayoutParams exampleButtonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         exampleButtonParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);

         exampleRowLayoutArray = new LinearLayout[rowsNeededInt];

         int exampleAddedCount = 0;
         for(int x = 0; x < rowsNeededInt; x++){
             exampleRowLayoutArray[x] = new LinearLayout(this);
             exampleRowLayoutArray[x].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
             exampleRowLayoutArray[x].setLayoutParams(rowsLayoutParams);

             for(int i =0; i < 6; i++){

                if(exampleAddedCount < examplerListCount){

                    String exampleNo = String.valueOf(exampleList.get(exampleAddedCount));

                    exampleButton[exampleAddedCount] = new TextView(this);
                    exampleButton[exampleAddedCount].setId(exampleAddedCount+1);
                    exampleButton[exampleAddedCount].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    exampleButton[exampleAddedCount].setText(exampleNo);
                    exampleButton[exampleAddedCount].setLayoutParams(exampleButtonParams);
                    exampleButton[exampleAddedCount].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    exampleButton[exampleAddedCount].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24);
                    exampleButton[exampleAddedCount].setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), ButtonNormal));

                    exampleRowLayoutArray[x].addView(exampleButton[exampleAddedCount]);
                    exampleAddedCount++;
                }

             }


             exampleLayout.addView(exampleRowLayoutArray[x]);

         }
```

**Xml**

```
<ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/examplescrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topbar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/examplelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
        </RelativeLayout>

   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: if you are using array of linearlayouts, why dont use ListView instead of relative layout?

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to need the `RelativeLayout`'s relative layout properties for anything, so the simplest would be to replace it with a vertical `LinearLayout`. Or if you need a scrolling list of items, consider a `ListView`.

In a `RelativeLayout`, you can achieve the same effect as vertical `LinearLayout` with the following:

- Generate an id for each child
- Create `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` with `LAYOUT_BELOW` rule referencing the previous child.
- Assign the layout params to the child.

Comment: I am using multiple horizontal LinearLayouts as a replacement for GridLayout that is not available in Android 2.3.3. I have tried using the support library, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I am using the RelativeLayout inside of the ScrollView because ScrollView can only have one direct child.

Comment: There's `GridView`, too.

Comment: I'll look into GridView. But there must be some simple way of getting the LinearLayouts to display beneath each other.

Comment: Yes, by placing them in a vertical `LinearLayout`.